# Symfony 2.4 No route found for "GET /new

Tags: symfony-2.3

I have creating a new *routing* for *DemoController*, but it ends up with

```
404 error.
"No route found for "GET/new".

404 Not Found - NotFoundHttpException
```

*1 linked Exception*: `ResourceNotFoundException.` How do I resolve it?

Here is the code:

```
_new:
    resource: "@AcmeDemoBundle/Controller/NewController.php"
    type: annotation
    prefix:  /new
```

### Controller

```
namespace Acme\DemoBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;

class NewController extends Controller
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        /*
         * The action's view can be rendered using render() method
         * or @Template annotation as demonstrated in DemoController.
         *
         */

        return $this->render('AcmeDemoBundle:New:indexs.html.twig');
    }
}
```

Comment: If think that, if you specify `type: annotation` in your `routing.yml`, you must write something above your NewController's indexAction. I'm not sure because I don't use annotations for routes, only YAML. (If I'm wrong, let me know, please)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I see your mistake.
As Dani said in comment, if you set annotation as type, you have to add the @route annotation on each action you want to run.

So, you have to do this :

Use the Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route Class
Add @Route("/", name="new_index") in your annotations

Here is the sample of code you can use :

```
<?php

namespace Acme\DemoBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;

class NewController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Index action.
     *
     * @return Response
     *
     * @Route("/", name="new_index")
     */
    public function indexAction()
    {
        /*
         * The action's view can be rendered using render() method
         * or @Template annotation as demonstrated in DemoController.
         *
         */

        return $this->render('AcmeDemoBundle:New:indexs.html.twig');
    }
}
```

One more thing, I have serious doubts about the relevance of your controller, especially with the chosen name. "New" is rather an action name and the name of your controller should be the name of the object you want to create through this route. For example, if you want to create cars, that is the controller I'd write :

```
<?php

namespace Acme\DemoBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;

class CarController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * new action.
     *
     * @return Response
     *
     * @Route("/", name="car_new")
     */
    public function newAction()
    {


        return $this->render('AcmeDemoBundle:Car:new.html.twig');
    }
}
```

Hope it helps !
Cheers,

Comment: That helped a lot, what i have to do in routing.yml?

Answer (score 0):

For the routing.yml part, you're good.
But if you want to follow my advice with the CarController example, here is the code you should write :

```
cars:
    resource: "@AcmeDemoBundle/Controller/CarController.php"
    type: annotation
    prefix:  /cars
```